# Query_posts $query_string

Tags: query-posts, query-string

I have a query that looks like:

`query_posts($query_string."&post_type=attachment&posts_per_page=9&paged=".$paged);`

I'd like it to looks something like:

```
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
query_posts($args);
```

I am trying to integrate `$query_string` into the `query_posts` with `$args`...can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Without knowing what that variable contains it's not possible to answer the question. I'd also advise against using `query_posts` in favour of `WP_Query` for new queries, and the `pre_get_posts` filter for replacing/modifying the main query

Comment: $query_string contains the search query.

Comment: You mean a standard WP search? Be precise in the words you use so we don't misunderstand, if we can see an example that would be great

Comment: Yes, just the standard...I don't have that variable defined...but I am using it on another site - it wasn't defined there either. Basically, all it does (to my understanding) is carry over the search query so you can run a custom query on the search results page. If that can be done using another variable, that's fine too.

Comment: possibly the closest you can get: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#preserving-existing-query-parameters, or generally, consider to work with 'pre_get_posts'  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I found the parameters I needed: https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628 (on Line 231)

```
//////Search Parameter
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter
's' => $s,                              //(string) - Passes along the query string variable from a search. For example usage see: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-the-number-of-results-in-wordpress-search 
'exact' => true,                        //(bool) - flag to make it only match whole titles/posts - Default value is false. For more information see: https://gist.github.com/2023628#gistcomment-285118
'sentence' => true,                     //(bool) - flag to make it do a phrase search - Default value is false. For more information see: https://gist.github.com/2023628#gistcomment-285118
```

I added `'s' => $s` to my `$args` which passes along the query string, which is what I was looking for :-)

My code now looks like:

```
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    's' => $s
);
query_posts($args);
```